# Run-time type casting based on size in c++

Tags: c++, templates, casting

I'm trying to recover the type of an array based on the size of its elements. I think I cannot use templates for this. Is there any way to achieve this without switch statements? Or if it is not possible without switch statements, is there a way to embed the switch statement into a class (caster). I like the caster class idea because there are many functions apart from copy that needs similar casting.

```
copy_region(uint8_t *, int);
copy_region(uint16_t *, int);
copy_region(uint32_t *, int);

void copier(uint8_t *ptr_element, int sz_element) {
   copy_region( caster(sz_element, ptr_element), n);
}
```

The switch solution I have is like this:

```
void copier(uint8_t *ptr_element, int sz_element) {
   switch(sz_element){
     case 1: copy_region( uint8_t*(ptr_element), n); break;
     case 2: copy_region( uint16_t*(ptr_element), n); break;
     case 4: copy_region( uint16_t*(ptr_element), n); break;
   }
}
```

I also thought of defining the operations as functors so that I might have a single switch statement, but the parameters for different operations are very dissimilar.

Edit:

The type information is not lost. I'm trying to implement a system (library/framework) with templated buffers. I have a base buffer class based on uint8_t as element. This class exists because I need to insert the buffers into a list. Base buffer class implements operations on these buffers. User specifies the buffer type as a template argument to the buffer class, but the library only sees the base buffer class and the type information (element size is enough to infer type).

Comment: How do you intend to find the size of the individual elements?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need 3 overloads of `copy_region()`?

Comment: Perhaps this is an instance of "state the goal, not what you think should be the first step". The design so far looks somewhat questionable.

Comment: I edited my solution to deal with the modified question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<int sz_element> void copier(uint8_t *ptr_element); //no definition
template<1> void copier(uint8_t *ptr_element)
{copy_region(uint8_t*(ptr_element), n);}
template<2> void copier(uint8_t *ptr_element)
{copy_region(uint16_t*(ptr_element), n);}
template<4> void copier(uint8_t *ptr_element)
{copy_region(uint32_t*(ptr_element), n);}
template<8> void copier(uint8_t *ptr_element)
{copy_region(uint64_t*(ptr_element), n);}
```

If the `sz_element` is not known at compile time, then you have to use a switch like you had in the OP.

There is no good that can come of this though.  Why do you have a `uint8_t*` that points to arbitrary data?  Get rid of that.

[EDIT]
You say you have a underlying class that is a buffer of uint8_t, and the users will use inherited classes with the type info.  In that case, to have sane code, you need virtual functions:

```
class base {
   vector<uint8_t> buffer;
public:
   virtual void copy()=0;
   virtual ~base() {}
};
template <class type>
class derived : public base {
public:
   virtual void copy() {}
   ~derived() {}
};
```

This will allow your library to use the functions without knowing the types, and yet no type information is lost.

Comment: thanks, I think I need the uint8_t* (edited the question to explain).

Comment: @perreal: if a class has the `virtual` keyword _ANYWHERE_, the destructor should be virtual as well.

Comment: @Mooing Duck To be slightly pedantic, the destructor should be public virtual OR protected non-virtual.

Comment: @MarkB: There's actually many situations where you don't have to mark it as virtual, but it makes a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of trying to achieve what you're looking to do here you should rethink your design.  Go to the source and record the type of the array in a special variable at the start of your memory block - or if possible, keep the type of the pointer you're passing around as the original type of the array so you can enforce type safety better.

There aren't many options left if you're already stripped the type information from your data without providing any mechanisms for finding out what it used to be in advance.

Comment: He can't put them in a list if he templates the base, which is the reason he added a base to begin with.